# Как воспользоваться psutil.Process.kill()?

Tags: python, python-2.x, psutil

Как использовать этот метод? psutil.Process.kill()
Мой код:

```
import psutil
psutil.Process.kill("calculator.exe")
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: unbound method kill() must be called with Process instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `kill` принадлежит классу `Process` и не имеет параметров.

Нужно получить список процессов, среди них найти нужный, и у него вызвать `kill`:

```
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name() == 'calc.exe':
        process.kill()
```